# English style conventions for standard C++ exception messages

Tags: c++, exception, conventions, standard-library

I'm asking about the strings returned by the *what* method of exceptions thrown by the standard library.
Do they usually start with a capital letter or a lowercase letter?
Do they usually end with a punctuation mark?

Is there any kind of convention for this that at least *most* standard library implementations adhere to?

Comment: No, nobody cares. Make it descriptive and stop worrying about things that don't matter.

Comment: "Something wrong happened."

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes "not working, blame programmer"

Comment: @CatPlusPlus gotta love your new bio on your profile.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely none. The exception message is basically irrelevant anyway and contains no useful information- same as the raw exception objects. Pretty much the only useful information is "An exception was thrown".

Answer (score 1):

In general, I'll agree with the previous comments and answer, with one exception (pun intended).  If you are are developing under a controlled quality system, your coding standard may stipulate how exceptions are reported.  As an example, the [FDA](http://www.fda.gov/downloads/RegulatoryInformation/Guidances/ucm126955.pdf) refers to "coding guidelines" for medical device software development. IEC 62304 more explicitly states the need for a software development process to rely on coding standards. So, on the contrary, someone may indeed care.

Having said that, it's interesting to note that the [JSF C++ coding standard](http://www.stroustrup.com/JSF-AV-rules.pdf) forbids exceptions (see p. 59), and [Google's coding standard](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Exceptions) forbids them, as well.

Comment: But the Google coding standard admits that that's only for practical legacy reasons, and that using exceptions is -- on the face of it -- a good idea.